# Handle multiple windows service

Tags: service, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am creating a windows service using quartz. I want to deploy this service at 3 places and it should work like if one service is down then second one should start, if second fails then last one should start. All the services are pointing to single database. May I know how can I implement these things.

@@Updated Question

In that, all the service are doing the same operation. I am having one column in my database as nextExecutionTime, if that exceeds from current Time means next service will start executing this job. Now the main problem I am facing is, if all three service will trigger at the same time, so it will fetch the data from database and try to update at the same time. So I need to reduce that concurrency error. May I know the solution for this. Do I need to implement some lock or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Are these three services doing same job ?? please elaborate ! however if i deploy these services on different systems how they aware of one another ? i dont know your exact requirement but i will accomplish this as follows : 
Assumption : Only one service should be doing job at a time rest of the service remain idle.

i will create some master column in some temp table.I will start any one service and set his name (pcname or location name) as a master along with last access time in this temp table.

Other services read the master and last access time.If last access time is more than current time then i assume that this service stop working so i make some other service which is available at time as a master and insert his details into temp table.

Comment: this is the same logic that I have applied, we have a logic as RowVersioning, even that doesn't work, it insert multiple entries in that table with same data because every job is inserting it own data. I think I am going wrong while locking that particular row.

Answer (score 0):

i have seen your updated question.As i said earlier in my answer create some lock table in your database and create lockholder (service name/pcname/locationname) and lastlockaccess timestamp(lastaccesstime by this service)column.Manually insert details for any one of the service and add extra code in each service which performed following tasks :

1> each window service connect to db and read the  lock table record
2> Suppose there are 3 service namely A,B,C and you enter lockholder as A initially that means service A is accessing the db.
3> When service B and C check lock table they will know that A is working on DB if lastlockaccess time for service A exceeds current time by some large margin then it means thats service A is stopped.So insert new entry programatically for Service B And C.whichever holds the lock will start executing.

hope this solution helps you however its not perfect solution.